# Making a Java file executable? "Could not find main class"?

Tags: java, web, jar, exe

I developed a program on Eclipse (October 2017). It's a GUI, but doesn't use the APPLET extension. I've been trying to figure out how to make it a simple executable so it doesn't require a compiler to run. Upon trying export it as a JAR Runnable, I get the following error:

[image]

I also tried a command line jar program, however I believe the versions aren't compatible as I get a bunch of errors in code that I don't get in Eclipse.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: bin/display : Unsupported major.minor version 53.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:803)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:442)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:64)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:348)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:347)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:312)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

At the bottom of my display class, I do have my main method

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    display show = new display();
}
```

I can't create a Web App out of it either, since it isn't an APPLET.

I've tried stuff, but I'm a little lost now.

Answer (score 1):

Your jar does not have a MANIFEST.MF file that indicates which Class is the Main class or entry to your application.

```
Project dir:
- root
-- source root
--- META-INF
---- MANIFEST.MF
```

Then inside your MANIFEST.MF file you will want the fully qualified package name of your main Class.  e.g.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: org.name.Main
```

Comment: This would be for the command line jar program, right? I did have a manifest.mf, but I might have it on the wrong location. Does it need to be with the .java files, or the .class files? Sorry for the lack of knowledge.

Comment: @ricknaght It should be in the META-INF dir within your project.

Answer (score 0):

In the launch configuration you didn't specify the class that has a `main()` method. It would probably be your `display` class.

Since your compiled classes targeted to JDK 1.8 you can't use runtime version lower than compiled one. Hence you got error about unsupported major minor version.

Jar is an utility to make Java archives and make them executable if you use command line options.

Another approach is to use third party utility such as [one-jar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net) .